# Sign in Doob's Inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I am reading Durrett's Probability Theory ad Examples. In chapter 4 the Doob's inequality is define as follows:

[image]

I am wondering what is $X_{m}^{+}$ in this case? I am not sure why there is a $+$ sign. Does it indicates that we are only considering the positive values of $X_{m}$? But then why cant we just use the absolute value of $X_{m}$? Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual definition is $X_m^+:=\max(X_m,0)$. This is also sometimes written as $X_m\lor 0:=\max(X_m,0)$.

Comment: Thank you! But what cant we just write$ |X_{m}|$? Aren't the two the same?

Comment: They are not the same, consider what happens when $X_m$ is negative. So $X_m^+\leq |X_m|$.

Comment: Great! That makes sense now! Thank you SO much!